# If I define a null character, how can I change it to the outside the function in JS?

Tags: javascript, xcode, function, module, this

There is my code.

```
const Product = function (id, date, pair, timeframe, shortLong, entry, tp, sl, size, wl, link, reasons, results) {
    this.id = id;
    this.date = date;
    this.pair = pair;
    this.timeframe = timeframe;
    this.shortLong = shortLong;
    this.entry = entry;
    this.tp = tp
    this.sl = sl;
    this.size = size;
    this.profit = (() => {
        
    });
    this.r = null;
    this.wl = wl;
    this.link = link;
    this.reasons = reasons;
    this.results = results;
}
const data = {
    products: [],
    selectedProduct: null,
    totalProfit: 0
}
```

I want to calculate r and profit side, but i can't. I tried like

```
this.profit = (() => {
        
});
```

this way, but Js doesn't allow this type functions i think.

How can I add to this values products array?

[Look this is my UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qyhw.jpg)

Comment: _"but Js doesn't allow this type functions i think"_ - what do you mean? After creating a product using `const p = new Product()` you can access the profit by using `p.profit`.

Comment: If I wrote the code's below
data.products.r = (()) => {}

Comment: That wouldn't work. 1. products is an array and doesn't have a `.r` method. 2. products is empty.

Comment: i have an html UI and in here i have a form, there is taking elements for this Product class.

but i am not taking r, so I should calculate it. but if i do it like this way it will give me a new r not in element Product, so i couldnt the way out.

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. So far the code doesn't do what you're describing.

Comment: I edited the post u can see the picture. I change r in uı actually, but in array, i cant change anything still

Comment: Not a picture please. Include a text-based [mcve].

Comment: https://github.com/erenyusufduran/Trading-Journal

Comment: Please read [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: Thanks for helping, I solved my problem. It was my first question in stackoverflow, I wasn't know smt. Your links teach me them aswell.